# Reduce formula character limit

Tags: formula, limits

I have the following formula:

```
OR
(
    AND
    (
        Route_to_Legal__c = TRUE,
        OR
        (
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Fulfillment/Supplier"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Promotion"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Purchase - Equipment"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Purchase - Tech (HW)"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Services - Non-Tech"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Venue/Event"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Customer"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Licensing/Revenue Share/Royalties"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "NDA [Non-Standard]"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Other"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Purchase - Real Estate"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Purchase - Tech (SW/SaaS)"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Outsourced Manufacturing Partner"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Raw Material/Freight"),
            AND
            (
                TEXT(Transaction_Type__c) = "No cost",
                INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Services - Tech (Labor)")
            )
        )
    ),
    AND
    (
        TEXT(Counter_Party_Access_to_PII__c) = "Yes",
        OR
        (
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Fulfillment/Supplier"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Promotion"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Purchase - Equipment"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Purchase - Tech (HW)"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Services - Non-Tech"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Venue/Event"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Customer"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Licensing/Revenue Share/Royalties"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "NDA [Non-Standard]"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Other"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Purchase - Real Estate"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Purchase - Tech (SW/SaaS)"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Outsourced Manufacturing Partner"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Raw Material/Freight"),
            AND
            (
                TEXT(Transaction_Type__c) = "No cost",
                INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Services - Tech (Labor)")
            )
        )
    ),
    AND
    (
        Agreement_Value__c >= 25000.00,
        OR
        (
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Fulfillment/Supplier"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Promotion"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Purchase - Equipment"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Purchase - Tech (HW)"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Services - Non-Tech"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Venue/Event"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Customer"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Licensing/Revenue Share/Royalties"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "NDA [Non-Standard]"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Other"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Purchase - Real Estate"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Purchase - Tech (SW/SaaS)"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Outsourced Manufacturing Partner"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Raw Material/Freight"),
            AND
            (
                TEXT(Transaction_Type__c) = "No cost",
                INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Services - Tech (Labor)")
            )
        )
    ),
    AND
    (
        Agreement_Value__c < 25000.00,
        OR
        (
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Licensing/Revenue Share/Royalties"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Purchase - Real Estate"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "NDA [Non-Standard]"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Other"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Customer"),
            AND
            (
                TEXT(Transaction_Type__c) = "No cost",
                INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Services - Tech (Labor)")
            )
        )
    ),
    AND
    (
        Multi_Year_Contract__c > 12.0,
        TEXT(Has_Exit_Clause__c) = "No",
        OR
        (
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Fulfillment/Supplier"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Promotion"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Purchase - Equipment"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Purchase - Tech (HW)"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Services - Non-Tech"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Venue/Event"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Customer"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Licensing/Revenue Share/Royalties"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "NDA [Non-Standard]"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Other"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Purchase - Real Estate"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Purchase - Tech (SW/SaaS)"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Outsourced Manufacturing Partner"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Raw Material/Freight"),
            AND
            (
                TEXT(Transaction_Type__c) = "No cost",
                INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Services - Tech (Labor)")
            )
        )
    )
)
```

It exceeds the maximum character limit of 3,900 characters. Is there a better way to write this formula to reduce the characters to get under the 3,900 limit?

Comment: Each of your inner OR statements seem to be repeated multiple times and seems to be a condition of every single branch. Can you consolidate those in one place?

Comment: A start could be to try to group the includes, so you don't have to repeat them so often.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using symbols to represent your conditions (or group of conditions) makes it easier to simplify boolean expressions. Having some education in formal logic and/or boolean algebra really helps out here.

Let `x` replace all of the following:

```
OR
        (
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Fulfillment/Supplier"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Promotion"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Purchase - Equipment"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Purchase - Tech (HW)"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Services - Non-Tech"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Venue/Event"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Customer"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Licensing/Revenue Share/Royalties"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "NDA [Non-Standard]"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Other"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Purchase - Real Estate"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Purchase - Tech (SW/SaaS)"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Outsourced Manufacturing Partner"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Raw Material/Freight"),
            AND
            (
                TEXT(Transaction_Type__c) = "No cost",
                INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Services - Tech (Labor)")
            )
        )
```

There's one iteration of that which is shorter

```
OR
        (
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Licensing/Revenue Share/Royalties"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Purchase - Real Estate"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "NDA [Non-Standard]"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Other"),
            INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Customer"),
            AND
            (
                TEXT(Transaction_Type__c) = "No cost",
                INCLUDES(Agreement_Type__c, "Services - Tech (Labor)")
            )
        )
```

let that be represented as `y`

The other parts are short enough, but for example's sake let's assign each one to a different letter, a-f.

That shortens our representation to this:

```
OR(
    AND(a, x),
    AND(b, x),
    AND(c, x),
    AND(d, y),
    AND(e, f, x)
)
```

In more standard boolean expression format
`(a && x) || (b && x) || (c && x) || (d && y) || (e && f && x)`

That `(d && y)` kinda messes us up a little bit. If that were `(d && x)` instead, we could simply take `x` out of each sub-expression using the *distributive property of logical and/or*
(i.e. `(a && x) || (b && x)` === `x && (a || b)`)

Not all hope is lost though. `y` is a subset of `x` (if `y` is true, then `x` must also be true), but I think the easier way to go about this would be to re-arrange and group things to make it easier for us to factor out the common elements.

Think of it like re-arranging a mathematical formula `2x + 4xy + 3y` as `2x(1 + 2y) + 3y`.

First, group things to help make it clear what we can factor out
`( (a && x) || (b && x) || (c && x) || (e && f && x) ) || (d && y)`

Then we can pull `x` out of the left sub-expression
`( x && (a || b || c || (e && f)) ) || (d && y)`

Now that *should* be precisely equivalent to the original statement, but it is possible I've made a mistake somewhere. Assuming I haven't, we can then turn that into the typical Salesforce formula format

```
OR(
    AND(
        x,
        OR(
            a,
            b,
            c,
            AND(e, f)
        )
    ),
    AND(d, y)
)
```

I'll leave the work of fully re-expanding that (replacing a-f and x and y with their actual conditions) to you.

Comment: Nice answer!!!!

Comment: Thank you Derek F!!